# Linked connection between MS SQL SERVER and Sybase ,Unicode problem

Tags: sql-server, unicode, linked-server, sap-ase

I added linked server on MS SQL SERVER 2008 with Sybase ASE 12.5 databases, 
everything works fine, but i've got problem with unicode strings.

from MS SQL when i'am running 
"SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ( SYTEST ,'SELECT Name FROM PRODUCT')"
and the result set contains wrong characters

a?›a??a??a? a?”
a??a??a?¬a??a? a??

Name column in Sybase is of nvarchar type , names are written in unicode.

Problem occurs only when ms sql server is running on windows server operating system,
There is no problem on ms sql-servers running on Windows 7 and XP, where I got correct result.

Answer (score 1):

try to use N@parameter when making query

Comment: Can you expand this to be a full answer?

Answer (score 0):

If it works on 2 separate installs, you compare and check the linked server settings using [sp_serveroption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178532.aspx), especially `collation compatible` and `collation name`

If these are the same, check any DSN and Sybase driver settings in the OS

Comment: Nothing changed situation,does some has any ideas? btw obds driver is: Adaptive server enterprise Driver version 15.5.0.8000
Driver ODBC Version 03.51

Answer (score 0):

There is a case like this in my company
I've created a linked server from SQL Server 2014 to the IBM AS/400 (i series) and faced with the same problem.

I'm not sure about the different between 2014 and 2008 handle the unicode chars but I think it not much, if any.

**How to**
1. login to the SQL studio
2. right click the linked server then select "properties"
3. select **"Server options"** in left pane
4. set **"Use remote collation"** to **"True"**
5. in **"Collation name"**, choose your unicode *(here is the basic list - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175%28v=sql.105%29.aspx"*

My problems solved this way! (I played a lot with connection strings with no desired results)